# PhoneGap LimeJS sound is not loading

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, javascript-framework, limejs

**I am using limejs with phonegap and facing a problem about sound**

**Lime.audio.Audio:** After following this [link](http://groups.google.com/group/limejs/browse_thread/thread/e6e4186e945f2698/32ef4a52ab3edb32?lnk=gst&q=sound#32ef4a52ab3edb32) of google group on stack overflow (thanx  **KenWong**) sound is playing on my iphone but it is not playing on my android.

Although the sound is working in google chrome but when I integrate the same code with phoneGap and execute it for android I hear no Sound.

```
        var welcomeSound = new lime.audio.Audio('assets/sounds/accordion.mp3');
        if(welcomeSound.isLoaded() && !welcomeSound.isPlaying()){
            alert('loaded');
            welcomeSound.play();

        }
```

- I checked the isLoaded() function. it is not loading the sound for
  android. is there any other way to load and play the sound properly 
  for android.
- i also simply try the phonegap sound api it is working well alone but
  I want to use the limejs.audio.Audio functionality.
- is there limitations of limejs.audio.Audio for android.
- I also try the different sound formats (like: .mp3, .ogg, .wav, .aac)
  for android. but still facing the same issue with limejs audio.
- :) all the sounds are working in google chrome on my MAC but not
  working on Android browser.
- and similarlyvery strange one is that sounds are not playing on MAC
  safari but playing smoothly on iphone safari.

Answer (score 0):

Lime.js creates and *audio* element to play your sound. Sadly the *audio* element is broken in the Android WebView which is used by PhoneGap. You will want to look at using the PhoneGap Media class instead.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html#Media

Comment: thanx for replying, I have used the phonegap media class for the sound it works well for android but when i integrate it with limejs :( again I have no sound. please guide me.